# Who really put to flight American hostages in America's embassy in Tehran in 1979?

Tags: united-states, iran, canada

Was it by Canadians or CIA? That's all! I think it doesn't need more contexts as it is a very clear question.

Please when you try to answer ( if you have an answer ) forget movies and imaginary stories. Send your answer associated with facts,references and evidences like a real fan of history.

Comment: I'm confused. If you are referring to the so called "Canadian Caper" (as dramatized in the movie Argo), the people involved were not US Embassy Hostages. They were people who happened to be in a separate building when the hostages were taken. Different group of people. They were never hostages.

Comment: And can one of down voters say what is wrong with the question to help correct it?

Comment: It looks like you might be working off of some stories about the Hostage Crisis with which many of us are unacquainted. You might have better luck if you start with the [standard story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_hostage_crisis#Release) of their release, tell us what variants from that you heard, and then ask us what you want to know..

Comment: @T.E.D. Look at ihtkwot's answer and learn! There is no reason for anger or passionate reactions. It is only a question to find answers. :)

Comment: To close voters: Really? Weird! because if it was ambiguous there was not any answer with 3 scores! It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is that **both** the CIA and Canadians were responsible for the escape of the American diplomats. The [Canadian Broadcasting Corporation](http://www.cbc.ca/archives/categories/politics/international-politics/revolution-in-iran/canadian-caper-helps-americans-escape-tehran.html), [Central Intelligence Agency](https://www.cia.gov/library/center-for-the-study-of-intelligence/csi-publications/csi-studies/studies/winter99-00/art1.html), [Al Jazeera](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2012/11/2012114716027857.html), [Ottawa Citizen](http://www.ottawacitizen.com/opinion/op-ed/other+Tehran/7773125/story.html), [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/05/world/americas/john-sheardown-canadian-who-sheltered-americans-in-tehran-dies-at-88.html?_r=0), [Montreal Gazette](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=EosxAAAAIBAJ&sjid=v6QFAAAAIBAJ&dq=escape%20from%20iran%20the%20canadian%20caper&pg=1286,2460024), and many other sources confirm the story.

Once the crisis started the CIA contacted the Canadians in Tehran, and coordinated with them to ensure the escape of the American diplomats. That is what the facts tell us because that is what happened.

Comment: @user37324 if your question is about who had the more "important" role in the operation then that is not a good fit for the site. All of the reputable sources say that it was a joint operation conducted by the CIA and Canadians. I answered your question about "who" put them on the plane, and the answer is unequivocally both the CIA and Canadians.

Comment: Once again you're referencing uncited "different stories". That puts the question out of scope for history.

Comment: Ok! It seems you are sensitive on words! I will try to make it more clear. Why are there different arguments which shows there is not an agreement between both Canadian and American governments about having a more important role in this matter? Because of it I asked to find which of them has a real role in it and which of them had an imaginary role in it only according to Hollywood scenarios?

Comment: @user37324 the CIA and Canadians cooperated together, any arguments about one or the other being more important is propaganda.

Comment: Cite the arguments - without citations, we're not doing history, we're just shuffling rumors around.  Ultimately there are arguments because the participants have differing priorities/agendas. Success has a thousand parents, failure is an orphan.

Comment: @Ryathal +1 Thanks! Your comment makes sense to me.

Comment: This answer appears to be about the "Canadian Caper", which **did not involve any of the embassy hostages**. You really ought to clarify that.